# Update Sqlite Database (from existing created database, without query) in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have already `Sqlite` database and I am using it in Android. Now, I want to update data in `Sqlite` database for next version of Android. So, I have entered data in Database and copied it in `asset` Folder.
So what changes I will need to do in code ?
**My Code :**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME = "dbJeeten";
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;

        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }

        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        mContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
    }
    }
}
```

I want that when user Update Application, Database updates itself.

**Error :**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

What changes i need to do ???

Comment: What about `onUpgrade`?

Comment: So instead of an upgrade, you want to replace the database file?

Comment: @CL., yes. Because it contains static data. I have added more records in new version. How to do it ?